# Remove words from a string that contain special characters

Tags: string-manipulation, text

I have a string like this:

`string="there is a humble-bee in Hanna's garden";`

Now I want to exclude those words that contain "-" and "'". My own solution would be:

`StringDelete[string,Cases[StringSplit[string," "], _?(StringContainsQ[#, {"'", "-"}] &)]]`

so the outcome is:

`"there is a  in  garden"`

But I was wondering whether there is a more elegant solution?

Comment: `Select[StringSplit@string, StringMatchQ[#, WordCharacter ...] &]` - you can pick out the words that don't completely contain WordCharacters into a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
StringDelete[string, WordCharacter .. ~~ "'" | "-" ~~ WordCharacter ..]
```

> ```
> "there is a  in  garden"
> ```

```
StringRiffle @ Select[StringFreeQ["'" | "-"]] @ StringSplit[string]
```

> ```
> "there is a in garden"
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You can give a string pattern to "StringDelete" like:

```
string = "there is a humble-bee in Hanna's garden";
pat = WordCharacter ... ~~ ("-" | "'") ~~ WordCharacter ...;
StringDelete[string, pat]
(*"there is a  in  garden"*)
```